# C# 2008 - NotifyIcon - BaloonTip

Tags: c#, tooltip, notifyicon

I'm using the following code:

```
notify.ShowBalloonTip(
    15000, 
    "Reminder!", 
    myText,
    System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.None);
```

But the problem is the balloon almost always hides one layer behind the active window. Obviously this doesn't work too well when your active window is maximized and goes all the way down to the task bar, because then the tip balloon is behind it. Does anyone know why this might happen? I'm using Win XP Pro SP3.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this really is just an XP thing. I just tried it on my machine which is running Windows 7 and it showed up on top every time.

Answer (score 1):

You might be experiencing a known (and annoying and random) Windows bug: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-fix-system-tray-tooltips-not-displaying-in-windows-xp/

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. I've noticed this other times (specifically, checking the date by hovering over the time, but the tooltip is behind the taskbar). Well, it seems there's some utility to help with this. And just when I thought Windows XP was perfect...